# Almost half a dozen

Tags: expressions, numbers, expression-choice

I understand, *dozen* may be more comfortable than *twelve* in speech.

I can understand using *over a dozen* or *almost a dozen* These imply rough measurement of the count, maybe ten, maybe eleven, or maybe thirteen, maybe fifteen.

But why do people choose to say/write *Almost half a dozen* or *Nearly half a dozen* when it invariably means "five"? "Four" is definitely not "nearly half a dozen", and I completely don't see the point why would anyone use this expression, but still I find it quite frequently. Does it have some historical basis or implies something beyond "five"?

Comment: 4 is not nearly 6? That's quite a subjective point of view.

Comment: @Matt Эллен: No, that's a third of a dozen, or maybe a notch over a quarter of a dozen. Nearly half? No way.

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much the definition of subjective.

Comment: I think this question is pointless. Most people rarely or never use *"almost half a dozen"* anyway - it virtually "flatlines" in NGram by comparison with [**about** half a dozen](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=about+half+a+dozen%2Calmost+half+a+dozen&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). But I will say that *"**nearly** half a dozen"*, though also relatively unusual, is 2-3 times more common than *"**almost** half a dozen"*.

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't quite hear well enough...did you say 'over a dozen' is 'maybe ten, maybe eleven', and then in comments say that 4 is -not- 'nearly half a dozen'?

Comment: The whole point of words like "almost" is that you're being vague about the exact number. If I said, "There are almost a hundred people here", what is the absolute minimum number that that might mean? 95? 90? 80? 60? The question is unanswerable: there is no absolute minimum. Is four "almost half a dozen"? I have no idea.

Comment: Jay, but they imply the value is near the given one. 60 is not near 100. And the smaller the digit the bigger the difference - If you say there's room for almost three people, I'd be very disappointed in you if two fail to fit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a mechanism for expressing uncertainty or unimportance of the exact number. For instance, if someone says

> We need to improve on-site safety. There have been five incidences in this month alone.

then you could be sure that there were exactly five of enough severity to count. However, if someone says

> We need to improve on-site safety. There have been almost half a dozen incidences in this month alone.

then maybe it was five incidences, or four and a smaller incidence, or five and a small incidence. This indicates that the actual number is unimportant; it's simply big enough to be an issue, and helps to keep the focus on the real problem.

Also, by using *almost* or *nearly* the speaker suggests that this number might rise unless something happens to change the situation.

Answer (score 4):

Language is not simply about conveying raw information. It's about emotions as well. Compare:

> There must have been four of five people fighting.
>
> There must have been almost half a dozen people fighting.

In my perception, the second sentence is much more emotional and implies that the number of people fighting is impressive.